# Android Change password of encrypted Room DB with SQLCipher

Tags: android-room, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I successfully encrypted my Room DB with SQLCipher.

I now like to give the user to option to change the DB password. So how can I change the SQLCipher password with Room DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
database.query("PRAGMA rekey = '$newPassword';", emptyArray())
```

As complete code example with context:

```
    fun changePassword(previousPassword: String, newPassword: String) {
        val passphrase = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(previousPassword.toCharArray())
        val factory = SupportFactory(passphrase)

        val database = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, <your_database_class>::class.java, "<database_name>")
            .openHelperFactory(factory)
            .build()

        database.query("PRAGMA rekey = '$newPassword';", emptyArray())
    }
```

There's even no need to close and re-open the database.