# Setting a password for Room on startup

Tags: kotlin, passwords, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, dagger-hilt

I'm using dagger-hilt

I want to set a password to Room. I know that I can do it like this:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDatabase(application: Application): MyDatabase {
    val passphrase: ByteArray = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes("my_password".toCharArray())
    val factory = SupportFactory(passphrase)

    return Room.databaseBuilder(application, MyDatabase::class.java, "my_database")
        .openHelperFactory(factory)
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()
}
```

But if the password is wrong I want to show a compose form with input to try another password.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my solution is:

- migrate to dagger2
- check password on startup
- if something is wrong - show login content and restart app if the new password is correct
- else - init dagger and set normal content

What helped me:

- secure preferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences
- restart app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46848226/16047039
- get context (this@MainActivity): https://medium.com/susheel-karam/different-ways-to-get-context-in-android-8018d9663292
- change password: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230727/16047039

My onCreate:

```
 class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {   
 .... 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val loggedIn = isDatabasePasswordCorrect(this@MainActivity, getSavedPassword())
    if (!loggedIn) {
        val content: @Composable () -> Unit = { Login() }
        setAppContent(content)
    } else {
        initDagger()

        val content: @Composable () -> Unit = { App() }
        setAppContent(content)
    }
}
....
}
```